# Ground state of 3 identical fermions laying over a circumference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, fermions

We are asked to show that the ground state in a system of 3 free identical fermions that are on a circle of length, 2$\pi$, is equivalent to $\sin(q_1-q_2)+\sin(q_2-q_3)+\sin(q_3-q_1)$ up to some scalar multiplication. Furthermore we are asked to find the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to the first excited energy level.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: For a circle the eigenfunctions are;
$$\psi_n = e^{(2\pi inq/L)}$$

Comment: Is there any interaction? Or just free fermions?

Comment: non interacting fermions. @daydreamer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eigenfunctions are
$$\psi_n={1\over\sqrt L}e^{2i\pi nq/L},\quad n\in\mathbb Z$$
with the associated energies $E_n={\hbar^2\over 2m}\left({2\pi\over L}\right)^2n^2$. Due to Pauli principle, the ground state of 3 fermions corresponds to one fermion in the state $n=0$, the second one in the state $n=+1$ and the third one in the state $n=-1$. The total energy is therefore $E_0+E_{-1}+E_1={4\hbar^2\pi^2\over mL^2}$. The wavefunction has to be anti-symmetric under the exchange of two fermions and can be written as a Slater determinant
$$\psi(q_1,q_2,q_3)=\left|\matrix{
     \psi_{0}(q_1) & \psi_{1}(q_1) & \psi_{-1}(q_1) \cr
     \psi_{0}(q_2) & \psi_{1}(q_2) & \psi_{-1}(q_2) \cr             \psi_{0}(q_3) & \psi_{1}(q_3) & \psi_{-1}(q_3) \cr
}\right|$$
which leads to
$$\eqalign{
 \psi(q_1,q_2,q_3)&={1\over L^{3/2}}\left|\matrix{
   1& e^{2i\pi q_1/L} & e^{-2i\pi q_1/L} \cr
   1& e^{2i\pi q_2/L} & e^{-2i\pi q_2/L} \cr
   1& e^{2i\pi q_3/L} & e^{-2i\pi q_3/L} \cr
  }\right|\cr
 &={2i\over L^{3/2}}\Big(\sin {2\pi\over L}(q_2-q_3)
+\sin {2\pi\over L}(q_1-q_2)+\sin {2\pi\over L}(q_3-q_1)\Big)
}$$

Comment: I don't think that's right: why do states rotating clockwise have positive energies while the ones rotating counter-clockwise have negative?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the square in the expression of the energy. It is corrected now.

Comment: so the dimension of eigenspace corresponding to the first excited energy level is 3? @Christophe

Comment: I would say 4, the first excited states being the Slater determinants constructed from the one-particle states $n=0,+1,+2$, $n=0,+1,-2$, $n=0,-1,+2$ and $n=0,-1,-2$ but I may be wrong... How do you get a number of 3?